# How to pass more than 2 input columns to a Deep learning Keras model for sequence tagging/labeling

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, nlp, labelling

I have to build a neural network which extract relationship between two entities.Input should be:
Input text/paragraph, vocabulary of entities and relationship phrases that system should recognize.

Output is sequence of tags and length of output sequence and input text/paragraph is same.

Dataset is a CSV file having 3 input columns(input text, entities in text, relationship between 2 entities) and 1 output column. I am using Keras library to build this model.

Example-**input1**: zomato acquires uber; **input2**: zomato, uber; **input3**: acquires
; **Output**: some-tag some-tag some-tag (**note**: these are not actual tags just an example)

I planned to use a char embedding for input text using time distributed layer with Bi-LSTM but now got stuck with 3 inputs.
I am aware of keras functional api but how can I use it in a sequence tagging problem with time distributed layer.
If any other approach can be used to avoid this problem, please suggest.

Comment: Why do you want to model three inputs? Tell me if I'm wrong but don't you want to get an output like - 
`[entity_1, relationship, entity_2] ` for `zomato acquires uber`?

Comment: Instead of exact keywords given in input  like entity_1, here I want to tag entity like" b-org relation b-org "and if sentence has words other than entity and relationship, 'Other' or 'O' tag will be added. So total 3 kinds of label are there b-org, relation and O in output.

Comment: Also this is just a simple example, relationship and entities can be anywhere in a sentence not necessarily in a sequence like the above example.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you don't have multiple inputs. You just have a single sequence to tag.

Comment: Why do you want to model different inputs?

Comment: I have 3 input columns. One column with sentences, second column with entities in sentences and third column with relationships between entities. Hope it helps to understand the problem.I want to train my model based on these 3 inputs columns.

Comment: You should use your entities and relationship column to tag your sentence. And then train the sequence tagging model using the sentence as input and tagged sequence as output.